# Index mongoDB with ElasticSearch

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

I already have MongoDB and installed Elasticsearch with [Mongoriver](https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb). So I set up my river:

```
$ curl -X PUT localhost:9200/_river/database_test/_meta -d '{
  "type": "mongodb",
  "mongodb": {
    "servers": [
      {
        "host": "127.0.0.1",
        "port": 27017
      }
    ],
    "options": {
      "secondary_read_preference": true
    },
    "db": "database_test",
    "collection": "event"
  },
  "index": {
    "name": "database_test",
    "type": "event"
  }
}'
```

I simply want to get events that have `country:Canada` so I try:

```
$ curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/database_test/_search?q=country:Canada'
```

And I get:

```
{
  "took": 2,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  }
}
```

I am searching the web and I read that I should first index my collection with Elasticsearch (lost the link). Should I index my Mongodb? What should I do to get results from an existing MongoDB collection?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The mongodb river relies on the operations log of MongoDB to index documents, so it is a requirement that you create your mongo database as a replica set. I assume that you're missing it, so when you create the river, the initial import sees nothing to index. I am also assuming that you're on Linux and you have a handle on the shell cli tools, so try this:

Follow these steps:

- Make sure that the mapper-attachments Elasticsearch plugins is also installed
- Make a backup of your database with mongodump
- edit mongodb.conf (usually in /etc/mongodb.conf, but varies on how you installed it) and add the line:

  `replSet = rs0`

  "rs0" is the name of the replicaset, it can be whatever you like.
- restart your mongo and then log in its console. Type:

  `rs.initiate()

   rs.slaveOk()`

The prompt will change to `rs0:PRIMARY>`

- Now create your river just as you did in the question and restore your database with mongorestore. Elasticsearch should index your documents.

I recomend using this plugin: http://mobz.github.io/elasticsearch-head/ to navigate your indexes and rivers and make sure your data got indexed.

If that doesnt work, please post which versions you are using for the mongodb-river-plugin, elasticsearch and mongodb.

Comment: Worked like a charm. I have been searching for quite some time. Thank you!

Comment: hi i have same problem...followed your answer but still getting same error..im using mongodb-2.6.1 ,elasticsearch "lucene_version" : "4.6" ,elasticsearch-river-mongodb-1.7.1 and elasticsearch-mapper-attachments/1.9.0

Comment: Does the actual ES index happen after mongorestore finishes?

Comment: If the river to the index is created, it should start while the mongorestore is still running, but I am not the author of the river and I know some things have changed with how the initial import happebs  since this answer was posted,  since it was for a very old version of ES, so this might not hold true for the current river version.